# Regex - replace quotes except attribute ones

Tags: regex, replace

I have a following text

```
<a href="#" class="name">here is "quoted"</a> and another in "quote" and alone quote - ".
```

and I need a regex where I am able to replace all quotes except quotes that wrap attribute values. So in the string above it will replace quotes wrapping words "quoted" and "quote" and the alone quote, but quotes wrapping "#" and "className" are not replaced as they're attribute values.

And the string becomes:

```
<a href="#" class="name">here is &quot;quoted&quot;</a> and another in &quot;quote&quot; and alone quote - &quot;.
```

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is a bit difficult to phrase using pure regex, due to the nested nature of your input.  One fairly simple approach to handle this uses the following regex pattern with a callback function:

```regex
<\w+.*?>|.*?(?=<|$)
```

In the event that we match an HTML tag, on the left side of the alternation, we do nothing.  Otherwise, we selectively replace all double quotes with `&quot;`.  Here is a sample Python script, although this problem can be handled similarly in most programming languages:

```py
import re

inp = '<a href="#" class="name">here is "quoted"</a> and another in "quote" and alone quote - "'
output = re.sub(r'<\w+.*?>|.*?(?=<|$)', lambda m: m.group().replace('"', '&quot;') if not re.search(r'^<.*>$', m.group()) else m.group(), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
<a href="#" class="name">here is &quot;quoted&quot;</a> and another in &quot;quote&quot; and alone quote - &quot;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, with additional processing this is OK. Unfortunately I was looking for a pure regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Regexr](https://regexr.com) is a great resource to see regex results live for the text on which you're trying to execute it, and it's what I used to figure out an answer for this.

What I came up with:
`(?<!=|="[^"]+)"`

How it works:
`?<!` 'negative lookbehind' - only match things that are not preceded by this expression. May not work in all browsers, but it seems to work in Chrome/FF
`=` - a literal equals sign, to make sure we're not hitting anything that looks like a property assignment like `href=`
`|` - acts like a boolean `OR` in regex, meaning match either side of this expression
`="[^"]+` - an equals sign, followed by a quote, followed by one or more characters that are not quotes
`"` - the quote we're actually trying to match for

This expression evaluates in total to "match all double quotes which do not follow either an equals sign, or some number of characters that were only preceded by an equals sign and an opening quote"

Comment: Thanks for this. This works great for Javascript engine, but not for PCRE. Is it possible to translate it to PCRE?